# Unable to understand the output in C++ Pointers. (Working with loops in pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers

Unable to understand the unexpected output. The pointer doesn't point to the 0th index no. of a string

I have been trying to find the reason for the output of the following program. the loop starts from i=0 but there is no character being displayed at the 0th index no. and the loop starts from the 1st index no.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
  clrscr();

  int i, n;
  char *x = "Alice";
  n = strlen(x);
  *x = x[n];

  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
  {
    cout << x;
    x++;
  }

  cout << endl << x;
  getch();
}
```

I am getting the following output: `liceicecee`
But I expected the output to start from 'A'.

Comment: *I am getting the following output:* -- You're lucky you're getting any output whatsoever, since you're trying to modify a string literal (undefined behavior, i.e. possible crash).  Also, what compiler are you using?  This looks like something from 30 years ago.

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` -- Unfortunately, this looks like `Turbo C++`.  No need to be using something from the last generation (more than 20 years old) and is non-standard.

Comment: [You need to change your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c53e666540a6dd4a).  Get it to compile in the online compiler (while you're installing something more modern, like Visual Studio 2019 Community or g++).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really upgrade to a modern compiler. There are many free ones available.

```
#include <iostream.h> // non-standard header file
#include <string.h>   // not recommended - it brings its functions into the global namespace

void main() { // main must return "int"
    int i, n;
    char* x = "Alice"; // illegal, must be const char*
    n = strlen(x);
    *x = x[n]; // illegal copy of the terminating \0 to the first const char

    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) { // <= includes the terminating \0
        cout << x; // will print: "", "lice", "ice", "ce", "e", ""
                   // since you move x forward below
        x++;
    }
    cout << endl << x; // x is now pointing after the \0, undefined behaviour
}
```

If you want to print the letters one by one (using your current program as a base) using standard C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    const char* x = "Alice";
    size_t n = std::strlen(x);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++x) {
        std::cout << *x; // *x to dereferece x to get the char it's pointing at
    }
    std::cout << "\n"; // std::endl is overkill, no need to flush
}
```

What `strlen` does is to search for the first `\0` character and to count how long it had to search. You really don't need to do that here since you are going through all the characters (by stepping `x`) yourself. Illustration:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char* x = "Alice";
    size_t n = 0;

    while(*x != '\0') {
        std::cout << *x;
        ++x;
        ++n;
    }
    std::cout << "\nThe string was " << n << " characters long\n";
}
```

Comment: Why promote the usage of undefined behavior?  `char* x = "Alice";...*x = x[n]`.  We're better than that here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It wasn't meant to promote it, just to explain it. I'll make changes....

Comment: `string.h` is a standard header file  (the C library headers may be included either as `.h` or `c` form)

Comment: Something like that yeah